# Metrics in rpart decision trees

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret, metric, rpart

I am currently working with decision trees in R, I am using caret library. Source code of rpart can be found here: https://github.com/cran/rpart/blob/master/R/rpart.R

I understand how decision trees are build. For example this model bellow:

```
   train(ReducedData[index,1:80], ReducedData[index,81],
                     method = "rpart",
                     trControl=trainControl("repeatedcv",number=5,repeats=5,
                                             summaryFunction=F2))
```

I want to change metrics to F2, which is predefined as it is defintion of F2 metrics. I know that learning happens in model$fit, I have checked how train() is build and it passes model's parameters to rpart::rpart()

Now my question:

Will rpart take into the account F2 metrics, or it will build tree due to normal impurity (which assumes that both type of errors are equivalent, but in F2 metric are not)?

If the second option is true, then does train just evaluate the model based on F2 for each fold in CV, and return the optimal one?

Thank you for all the help.

EDIT: I didn't ask the question well. If 2 is true, which with help from the comment we conclude that appearently is, how can I achieve that algoritm will recognize FP error in unbalanced classification? Oversampling does not give good results.

Is there any way that you can pass metric parameter to the learning process of algorithm? Not to all of the models ofc, but something like decision trees, where impurity could depend on given metric?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? See: `?train` and `?trainControl`. The `summaryFunction` is only about summary statistics to compute and return at each step. caret package is just a warper over other functions, so if you want to learn how does rpart works, check its docs.

Comment: So if I want to build tree with F2 metric I have to change source code of rpart? Or is there an easier way to tell that FP error is more expensive?

Comment: Basically yes, but why would you like to do this..?

Comment: I am dealing with unbalanced classification problem and oversampling tehniques does not give any useful results. I want to change rpart so later when I perform manual Random Forest I can call the edited function.

Comment: Oversampling is just one of the many available approaches to unbalanced classes (there is tons of literature on this, just google it). Changing the source code should be the last thing that you should try...

Comment: Any suggestions? I did lot of googling and tried most of them, this is kinda last thing that is left. I tried: Oversampling, undersampling, SMOTE, penality approach, I defined cost of both errors, I alos tried to extract similiar data with grouping tehniques and then again do on subsets all of the above for each group.

Comment: Which gives some results ofc, but I wonder if I could do better with something like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80115/discussion-between-jacobjacox-and-tim).